# Standard ML binary tree type

Tags: types, tree, sml

I'm studying ML in class and I've run into a homework problem I am stuck on. I've spent all day yesterday searching but made little progress and we did not talk about this in class, so I am hoping you guys can help me.

We are given:

```
datatype which = STRING of string | INT of int
```

Part 1. We are told we need to create another datatype named `whichTree` for a binary tree containing the values of type `which` where data is only at the leaves of the tree.

Part 2. We need to create a `whichSearch` function having type `whichTree -> int -> bool` returning true or false based on whether the int is in the tree.

This is what I have so far:

```
datatype which = STRING of string | INT of int;
datatype whichTree = Empty | Node of int*whichTree*whichTree;

val t1 = Node(6, Node(4,Empty,Empty), Node(15, Node(11,Empty,Empty), Node(24,Empty,Empty)));
val t2 = Node(157,Empty,Empty);
val t3 = Node(102,t1,t2);

fun whichSearch (i, Empty) = false
| whichSearch (i, Node(entry, left, right)) =
    if i = entry then true
    else whichSearch (i, left)
    orelse whichSearch (i, right);
```

The problem I am now facing is this:

1. My `whichTree` does not contain the type `which`. I am not sure how I can fix that.
2. I should have my `whichSearch` function of type `whichTree -> int -> bool` but it is `int * whichTree -> bool` and am working on trying to figure out how to fix things. I am not sure how I would go about fixing this as I have to specify a value for `i` in `whichSearch` to search for. I'm searching on this but any tips would be great.

Can anyone help? If so thank you! And thank you to the guys who already responded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you've come up with, I think I should point out a few rules in the Standard-ML language that you are breaking, which I hope will make it easier for you to procede:

- Each name you introduce, be it a type, function or variable, can only mean one thing (as long as they are in the same scope in the program).

  - You break this by first defining a datatype `which` and then defining a function by the same name.
  - You also break it by first defining a datatype `whichTree` and then defining another datatype by the same name.
  - You actually also break it on the 3rd line, by introducing two new datatype constructors (`STRING` and `INT`) that were already introduced on the 1st line. Remember that when you use these `datatype` declarations, you're not only defining a type name but also the constructors for the type.
- If you wish to introduce a datatype constructor taking two parameters, which it looks as though you want to do on line 3, you should use an asterisk `*` between the types, not the arrow operator `->`.

I would also agree with Victor, you should think in general terms about what a binary tree actually is, conceptually. Then translate this into Standard-ML.

---

**Edit after the code in the question was rewritten:** Your new code is much better. As you point out, you stand now with two questions:

1. How do you make the tree a tree of `which` values? Well, your tree is currently a tree of `int` values, so doesn't it make sense that you should change `int` for `which`? But you also state that your tree datatype should be "a binary tree containing the values of type "which" where data is only at the leaves of the tree". This is distinct from what you've currently coded, which keeps an `int` at every **non-leaf** node. The non-leaf nodes are determined by the recursive case in the datatype declaration, while the leaf nodes are determined by the non-recursive case.
2. A function of type `(A * B) -> C` (where A, B and C are types) can be rewritten to be of type `A -> B -> C`. Both are valid and usable in Standard-ML, but the second form is usually preferred in functional programming languages because it allows a technique known as **currying**, which means "partial function application". To make the change, you basically write parameters in a different way: Instead of `myFunction(a, b)`, you write `myFunction a b` -- both where you define the function and where you use it.

Note that I suggest you handle point 2 later, first focus on getting the datatypes correct and getting a working search function, then you can change its type when you know it's otherwise correct.

Comment: I redid things on paper and found a few other tutorials I use. I am on the right track now. The real issue is I do not know much about datatype declarations other than what I've learned yesterday and today. I am getting closer and will have to search on how to define one datatype by another as you are suggesting.

Comment: I expanded my answer based on your amended question. Remember that on Stack Overflow, you are supposed to give votes to helpful answer and accept an answer at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about ML. Using pen and paper (or marker and white board), can you explain how a binary tree containing your data in the leaves would look like? Can you explain in broad terms how you would search for an element in the tree? (hint: a search needs to traverse nodes by deciding whether to go left or right, so you *need* to keep some information in the tree nodes to help the search algorithm decide).

Once you ave the representation and algorithms laid out as english sentences, translating them to SML will be easier.

Comment: The issue i was having was figuring out how to create trees in ML. I am aware that my old code looked very strange but I was guessing. I'm on the right track now and have my code looking left and right. Thank you for the advice. In a few hours hopefully I can do the same things to correct my types and then all will be well :)